# Is there a way to automatically generate a Spring Bean from a static Java utility class?

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I have a legacy static class that has a bunch of static methods:

```
public class Util {
   public static void op1(String param_string) {
      System.out.println("op1 " + param_string);
   }

   public static void op2(int param_int) {
      System.out.println("op2 " + param_int);
   }
}
```

Our unit tests are much better when we don't deal with statics!

So we would like to create a spring bean that basically just acts as a proxy to this so we can `@Autowire` it and not deal with static methods:

```
@Component
public class UtilBean {
   public void op1(String param_string) {
     Util.op1(param_string);
   }

   public void op2(int param_int) {
     Util.op2(param_int);
   }
}
```

In my case, there are like 40 classes and I'm looking for a way to make this easier.

Is there some way to do this without having to type out each one?

To rephrase the question: Is there some way to automatically generate a spring bean from a static Java utility class?

Is there some way to use Lombok to do this?

Comment: Reflection and proxies come to mind

Comment: i'm thinking there is no library that can do this unless maybe Lombok, maven plugin etc because it is a compile time ask

Comment: Proxies can be generated at runtime. Using a `@Configuration` with `@Bean` annotated methods can then return the correct proxy.

Comment: runtime proxy does not solve this issue, unless i'm missing something

Comment: Why not? With reflection, you get references to all methods in your util class(es) and store them in a collection/map. Then you generate the proxy and have it delegate the calls to the methods of the util class. Nevermind, I just realized that a dynamic proxy requires an interface to implement. Forget what I said. Sorry for wasting your time